# Can't add UUID to developers account

Tags: ios, xamarin

This should be easy but.. I'm trying to add my Iphones UUID to my developers account, but somehow when I try to reach the `Certificates, IDs & Profiles` page I get redirected the `https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome` where the `Getting Started` info is still being showed. I'm so annoyed, because I can't fix this: `I just can't  Error: No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys.`

Comment: which browser are you using? try to login in diff one

Comment: @NitinGohel I tried it on both chrome and safari, both browsers redirect me to the welcome page....

Answer (score 0):

1)ensure your Xcode have developer account =>  cmd+','
[account infor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNHv7.png)

2)download all 
[provisioing profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjM3U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

We have faced similar kind of weird problems related to apple developer site,and the solution we found so far was..

1)Clear all the cache of the browser

2)Even after clearing the cache data if did not work kindly check with other computer, and it will definitely work.

Also make sure that your developer account is valid,and check for expiration of dev account.